# VSCode tomcat project fails to publish

Tags: maven, tomcat

I am trying to setup tomcat in VSCode. Previously I was working with Eclipse.
Plugins that I'm using for that:

1. [Community Server Connectors](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-community-server-connector)
2. [Runtime Server Protocol UI](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-rsp-ui)
3. Plugins for Java and Maven.

Now I keep getting this error

```
[C:\Servers\tomcat\webapps\myApp] is not valid
```

And when I open the folder, indeed, myApp is not there.

For each deployment, I added WebContent folder to the server as Exploded.
This is the part of the server configuration file.

```
  "deployables": {
    "c:\\MyProject\\myApp\\WebContent": {
      "label": "c:\\MyProject\\myApp\\WebContent",
      "path": c:\\MyProject\\myApp\\WebContent,
      "options": {}
    },
<...>
```

```
 "server.base.dir": "C:\\Servers\\tomcat",
  "server.classpath.additions": "",
  "server.deploy.dir": "${server.base.dir}\\webapps",
  "server.home.dir": "c:\\Program Files\\apache-tomcat",
  "server.http.host": "localhost",
  "server.http.port": "8080",
  "vm.install.path": "C:\\Program Files\\jdk-11",
```

Any suggestions on how can I fix it? Or how I can approach this problem?

So far I tried:

1. Using not Exploded option
2. Changing configuration
3. Deploying the parent folders of  WebContent

Also I ran maven clean install, and I see that target folder is not empty.